# find Service's life cycle in Android source codes

Tags: android, static-analysis

I've downloaded Android source codes and find such things as `Context.java` lying in the `frameworks/base` directory. Thus, I can look around and know how an Android method is implemented. However, if I want to look at the life cycle of `Service` or `Bound Service`, which directory should I turn to? To be more specific, we know `onBind` method will return an `IBinder` object so I wonder where the object goes or who it is assigned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding the [android sources](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) plugins to my eclispe, I'm able to read source codes in the android.jar. Then debugging by step enables me to have a taste of the guts of android

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code and do a file search for keywords you are looking for. A lot of the service methods are called using AIDL because services can exist in different processes.